# How do I find civicrm field names for import?

Tags: civimember, import, relationships

I want to import memberships, but civi isn't finding the membership type. How do I find out the field names (such as membership_type) for each membership?  This problem has cropped up for other imports.  For example, I'd like to be able to import relationships.

Is there a tool that I need outside of civi?  Is there someplace in civi where I can find this type of information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When importing memberships the type needs to match name of the type from the first column on the membership page (Administer => CiviMember => Membership Types).  So if you've defined a membership type of "Gold Member" then when importing, you need to put Gold Member in the column for membership type in the CVS.

Importing relationships is a bit trickier.  You can only import one type of relationship with each cvs file.

Have you looked at the on line book on importing.  It gives some good examples and tips on importing.

http://gitbook.civicrm.org/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm.html

Answer (score 2):

If you upload any csv to the Import Memberships wizard and then click through to the second screen, on the right you will see a drop down that will show you the list of fields that the Import can accept. That will include fields such as External ID, Email etc one of which will be required to match to the contact, as well as Membership Type, Membership Status, Membership Since, Membership Start Date.

If you have made custom Membership fields, then they should be shown in the drop down too.

Relationships can be imported via the Import Contacts wizard, but as Paul says, only a single Relationship Type at once. These live right at the bottom of the selector, ie after World Region etc. You choose the 'relationship type' that is to be created, then select the field that you have for the related contact you are making, eg Organisation Name if you are adding the Employer as part of importing the Employees. HTH

Comment: Just to be very clear, the link for Import Memberships is under Memberships in the Admin Menu eg at /civicrm/member/import?reset=1, where as for Relationships you use Import Contacts, under Contacts in admin menu, ie at /civicrm/import/contact?reset=1.  You cannot import Membership records in the same process as importing the Contacts. First import Contacts, then use eg External ID to match the Membership records that you import in the next process.